# Generate table with latex

Tags: tables

How can I generate this table in Latex? I have tried various codes but did not. I would appreciate any help.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us the compilable code you have tried so far ...

Comment: Please be much more specific about the elements of the table that should be reproduced. E.g., must the three columns be equally wide? Must the first row and the first column be shaded in light gray? Which cells must be in bold, and which ones must be non-bold? By the way, I can't help but remark that the screenshot you posted shows a table that's singularly unattractive and boring. Are you obligated to replicate all of its unattractive and unappealing aspects, or are you free to accept a better-looking, more pleasing layout?

Answer (score 3):

- Let’s use `tabularx` so that the columns “south” and “north” would have the same length. We will define a new column type, Y, so that the content would be centered.

  - Package `SIunitx` to use units like gigawatt or percent
  - Package `multirow` for the forth row
  - **For the caption** : we must use `tabularx` in a `table` environment and use `caption` after the table

Here we go:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| >{\bf}c | Y | Y |}

\hline
&   \textbf{South}
&   \textbf{North}  \\

\hline
    Demand      
&   $\SI{1.0}{\giga \watt}$ -- $\SI{2.4}{\giga \watt}$
&   $\SI{2.9}{\giga \watt}$ -- $\SI{9.8}{\giga \watt}$  \\

\hline
    Non-synchronous energy
&   $\SI{36.5}{\percent}$
&   $\SI{16}{\percent}$ \\
    2015, in percentage
&   ($\SI{2}{\giga \watt}$ wind, $\SI{5}{\mega \watt}$ PV)
&   2017 (windfarms)    \\

\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Interconnectors}
& 1AC
& \multirow{2}{*}{3 HVDC} \\
& HVDC
&   \\

\hline

\end{tabularx}

\caption{Analogy between South and North}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

i would design your table as follows:

[image]

it is obtain by use of packages `booktabs` for horizontal rules, `makecell` for column headers, vertical spaces around in cells' contents and for two short lines cells contents, and for numbers range macro `SIrange{<value 1>}{<value 2>}{<units>}` from `siunitx` package (`\SI{...}{...}` and others `siunitx` macros are normally used outside math environment).

in effort to make code concise and clear (as much as it is possible to my knowledge :-) ), i exploit `node distance` for positioning node and coordinates and  use descent (correct) `latex` syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage[skip=1ex, font={bf,it}]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Analogy between South and North}
    \label{tab: comparison}
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\bfseries}l C C}
    \toprule
            &   \thead{South}       &   \thead{North}                   \\
    \cmidrule{2-3}
Demand      &   \SIrange{1.0}{2.4}{\giga\watt}
                                    &   \SIrange{2.9}{9.8}{\giga\watt}  \\
    \midrule
Non-synchronous energy
            &   \SI{36.5}{\percent} &   \SI{16}{\percent}               \\
2015 [\%]   &   (\SI{2}{\giga\watt} wind, \SI{5}{\mega \watt} PV)
                                    &   (Windfarms) , 2017              \\
Interconnections
            &   \makecell[t]{1AC\\ HVDC}
                                    &   3 HVDC                          \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

*note:* i wouldn't use colors in table. about design nice tables see [Wie Tabellen eigentlich aussehen sollten](https://wiert.me/2014/04/03/andre-vatter-google-wie-tabellen-eigentlich-aussehen-sollten-%EF%BB%BF/).